# why file upload not working in webview android

Tags: java, android, webview, upload

I have implemented this within webview to upload files on website opened in webview but it is not working. I just want to know a solution  that for example facebook is opened in webview so when user click upload on website it should perform operation as it do in chrome. But now nothing happens when i click upload. Why ?

also this webview in static class.

```
myview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
        mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        i.setType("image/*");

        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Browser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
    }
});
```

Comment: Check if this link helps for you: http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106

Comment: and http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/